# Write a Hibernate or JPA native SQL on two flat tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I have two flat tables. There is no relationship between them. I have to use either JPA or Hibernate and retreive data from those tables using hql or native sql query. This query is part of a stored procedure.  So, my other option is to call this ref cursor stored procedure and retrieve the data.

Here is my query.

```
/ * GET ALL THE COLUMNS FROM T2 */
SELECT 
     T2.*    
    FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
    WHERE T1.USERID = 'TESTUSER'    AND T2.GROUP_CAT IN (
    T1.GROUPCAT1,T1.GROUPCAT2,T1.GROUPCAT3,T1.GROUPCAT4, T1.GROUPCAT5)
```

How do I write retrieve data either in Hibernate or JPA?

Comment: I more prefer Criteria,  more type safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create hibernate entity (T2Entity) for table - T2.
2. Create a DAO for entity T2, lets call it as T2Dao which inherits from generic Dao.
3. Entity manager is injected in generic Dao using below annotation:

   ```
   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager entityManager;
   ```

   It has setter and getter method for entityManager.
4. In T2Dao, define the method like below (uses JPA):

   public List findT2Entities() {

   ```
   String nativeSQL = "SELECT T2.* FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.USERID = 'TESTUSER'    AND T2.GROUP_CAT IN (T1.GROUPCAT1,T1.GROUPCAT2,T1.GROUPCAT3,T1.GROUPCAT4, T1.GROUPCAT5)";

   Query q=this.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(nativeSQL,T2Entity.class);

   try{
       List<T2Entity> t2EntityList  = (List<T2Entity>) q.getResultList();
       return t2EntityList;
   }catch(NoResultException e){
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }
5. For better performance, index the columns T1.USERID,T2.GROUP_CAT, etc., in database; make sure nativeSQL doesn't do sequential scan on the tables.

you can do other optimization based on your use-case.

Comment: Thanks Balaji! I am using session factory. Here is what I came up with. `List list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from com.abc.Usergroup UG, User U where U.loginid =? and UG.userGroup in (U.usergroup1, U.usergroup2, U.usergroup3, U.usergroup4, U.usergroup5, U.usergroup6, U.usergroup7, U.usergroup8)") .setParameter(0, userId).list();`      It returns both the tables. I need to get just the second one; working on it.

Comment: @Superman9999,   You are missing select clause in the query. After joining two tables, you are selecting all columns of the joined resultset. Add select clause and list columns you need (select User from com.abc.Usergroup UG, User U ....)  Refer links : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html         http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

Comment: Sorry I figured that out a while back, did not get a chance to come here and update the thread. I used `select UG from....` to get what I want. Thanks for your help!!